# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_substr()

Tags: php, string

I wanted to see your input on this concern I'm currently experiencing.
It turns out that:

```
 <?php
$disc_t=$name; 
  if(strlen($disc_t)<=15)
  {
   $name_now=mb_substr( strip_tags($disc_t), 0, 10 ).'';
  }
  else
  {
   $name_now=mb_substr( strip_tags($disc_t), 0, 10).'...';
  }
?>
```

is somehow giving me an error on the site, the error shows:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_substr() in /home/(website)/public_html/index.php on line 308
```

I don't quite understand what they mean by `mb_substr`, is this a PHP version error?
I am currently using PHP 5.3.19

Comment: your php does not have mbstring enabled.http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

Comment: Your server probably doesn't have the mb_str module

Comment: how can i enable this module? i'm new to server configuration.

Comment: can you edit your php.ini file? if you can't answer that question, what are you running on?

Comment: i think i should be able to edit the php.ini in my website, however do i enable it via the root cpanel? or the cpanel located in my accounts list? (example: /home/blahwhore/public_html/)

Comment: This might help http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/enable-install-mbstring-module-158165.html

Comment: FYI, the question is as important as the answer. If you found a solution, please leave the original question in tact, and post the resolution as an *answer*.

Comment: Don't forget to restart apache2 on Ubuntu machines after installing the extension

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Throw this into a terminal:

```
php -m | grep mb
```

If `mbstring` shows up then it should work.

Comment: i see `mbstring.encoding_translation` set to OFF

Comment: Look in your `php.ini` file. Search for `extension=` and look through the list of extensions. If there is one with the name `mbstring` in it then the extension should be installed. If the line is commented out (has a `;` in-front of it) then it is not enabled... remove the `;`, and restart Apache (or whatever server you are using).

Comment: Problem solved, turns out it was that i didn't have said option enabled as you've mentioned.

Answer (score 37):

[`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/mb-substr) is a multibyte-safe version of [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr), meaning it works with *characters* as opposed to *bytes*. This is most noticeable in UTF-8, where many characters are represented by two or more bytes.

According to the [installation instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php), `mbstring` is not a built-in extension. You must enable it by having the appropriate files and configuring PHP correctly. Some information can be found in the link provided, your webhost should be able to help you with the rest.

To see if mbstring is installed:
`php -m | grep mbstring`

For Linux, install using

`sudo apt-get install php-mbstring`

Comment: do you know where i download the files so i can install mb_substr?
Or do i just run a command?

Comment: You shouldn't install `php7.0-mbstring` as it will remain at version 7.0 even when PHP is upgraded to 7.1 and beyond. You should instead install `php-mbstring`

Comment: very safe, except if you push it to prod that has this module disabled then it will crash the application :)

Comment: @GregWoz Well yeah, but that's what deployment testing is for :p

Comment: Yeah if one isn't blessed with a big legacy system to fix =)

Answer (score 2):

If you have root access, you can configure it using WHM Panel or using Command Line. I will let you know how you can do it using WHM Panel.
1.  Login to your WHM with Root User
2.  Go to Easyapache
3.  Go to previously saved configuration 
4.  Click on Start Customizing based on Profile.
5.  Don't change apache and php version, just click next.
6.  Click on Exhaustive options list at the bottom of php configuration
7.  Select the checkbox near MBString option
8.  Save and Build
**9.  Do not close your browser window if it takes a while. Be patient.**
You are Done!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by executing the following package in Red Hat Linux 8.

```
dnf install php-mbstring
```

Answer (score -2):

The error is telling you that you are trying to use a function named mb_substr that doesn't exist.

Perhaps you can achieve the same result using the substr function http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php  instead.  substr(strip_tags($disc_t), 0, 10) will return the first ten characters of the result of strip_tags($disc_t) .