# Extracting sub string from web page content

Tags: php, substr

I am parsing web page data using `file_get_content`. Now I want to extact first 150 character as a description for that url.

```
                $url = 'http://crewow.com/CSS_Layout_Tutorial.php';
                $data = file_get_contents($url);
                $content = plaintext($data);
                $Preview = trim_display(140,$content); //to Show first 100 char of the web page as preview
                echo $Preview;

    function trim_display($size,$string)

        {

            echo "string is  : $string <br/>";

            $trim_string = substr($string, 0, 150);

            $trim_string = $trim_string . "...";
            echo "Trim string is  $trim_string <br/>";
            return $trim_string;
           }

function plaintext($html)
{
    $plaintext = preg_replace('#([<]title)(.*)([<]/title[>])#s', ' ', $html);
    // remove title 

        //$plaintext = preg_match('#<title>(.*?)</title>#', $html);
    // remove comments and any content found in the the comment area (strip_tags only removes the actual tags).
    $plaintext = preg_replace('#<!--.*?-->#s', '', $plaintext);

    // put a space between list items (strip_tags just removes the tags).
        $plaintext = preg_replace('#</li>#', ' </li>', $plaintext);     

        // remove all script and style tags
    $plaintext = preg_replace('#<(script|style)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</(script|style)>#is', "", $plaintext);
    // remove br tags (missed by strip_tags)
        // remove all remaining html
        $plaintext = strip_tags($plaintext);
    return $plaintext;

}
```

This code works well for some url. For few it does not show any thing in $Preview. 
Data sent to `trim_display()` correctly but fails `$trim_string = substr($string, 0, 150);`.

Output of this remail empty.

Comment: What do you function "plaintext" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [substr() or mb\_substr() does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222999/substr-or-mb-substr-does-not-work)

Comment: Did you debug $content?

Comment: @SergeyNLukin: I added plaintext

Comment: @VijayVerma: Yes, $content give correctly page content

Comment: 1) as you can have a lot of spaces in begging in your $content, I suggest to trim() it.
2) Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.

Comment: @SergeyNLukin: thanks, how can I know that there is only space in beggining and also removing only those extra spaces?

Comment: use ltrim() always. It will strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually user code is correct and working also correct. But unfortunately is not returning any  character with 150 character. Try 5000 .

```
$trim_string = substr($string, 0, 5000);
```

To understand this problem see view source.

You can use this code instead of your and definitely it will work:

```
$url = 'http://crewow.com/CSS_Layout_Tutorial.php';
 $data = file_get_contents($url);
 $content = plaintext($data);
 //echo trim($content);
 $Preview = trim_display(150,trim($content)); //to Show first 100 char of the web page as preview
 echo $Preview;

 function trim_display($size,$string)
 {

            //echo "string is  : $string <br/>";

            $trim_string = substr($string, 0, 150);

            $trim_string = $trim_string . "...";
            //echo "Trim string is  $trim_string <br/>";
            return $trim_string;
 }

function plaintext($html)
{
    $plaintext = preg_replace('#([<]title)(.*)([<]/title[>])#s', ' ', $html);
    // remove title 

        //$plaintext = preg_match('#<title>(.*?)</title>#', $html);
    // remove comments and any content found in the the comment area (strip_tags only removes the actual tags).
    $plaintext = preg_replace('#<!--.*?-->#s', '', $plaintext);

    // put a space between list items (strip_tags just removes the tags).
        $plaintext = preg_replace('#</li>#', ' </li>', $plaintext);     

        // remove all script and style tags
    $plaintext = preg_replace('#<(script|style)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</(script|style)>#is', "", $plaintext);
    // remove br tags (missed by strip_tags)
        // remove all remaining html
        $plaintext = strip_tags($plaintext);
    return $plaintext;

}
```

Comment: correct. But if I have small box to show preview. Taking 5000 does not work for me. What is the problem in above case?

Comment: @Programming_crazy did you got, what I want to say in my answer?

Comment: you need to trim content.

Comment: I could not. Dont know which content I have to trim.

Comment: I edit the answer. Please check it. Hopefully your problem should be resolve.